# Sum consecutive observations by some variable

Tags: sas, retain

I'm just learning to use SAS, so bear with me a bit. I have the following sample patient data on prescription usage and I'd like to try to combine observations to form more of a patient story, but keep the timeline intact:

```
data have;
 input dose $2. id $4. supply date $8.;
 datalines;
 "5" 1234 30 01012015
 "10" 1234 30 02012015
 "10" 1234 30 03012015
 "5" 1234 30 04012015
 "2" 1234 30 05012015
 "5" 4321 30 07012016
 "2" 9876 30 05012016
 "2" 9876 30 06012016
 "10" 9876 30 07012016
 ;
run;
```

Where dose is the dosage in mg, id is patient ID, supply is the number of days' supply of the medication, and date is the date of the refill.

I'd like to consolidate some of the observations so that when we look at patient 1234 we can see they were taking 5mg for 30 days, then 10mg for 60 days, then 5 mg again for 30 days, etc. All of the summation and group by commands I've learned would combine observations 1 and 4 together, but the patient story was that the dosage was increased and then decreased, and I'd like to keep that intact but don't know how.

So it would look like this:

```
data want;
 input dose $2. id $4. supply date $8.;
 datalines;
 "5" 1234 30 01012015
 "10" 1234 60 02012015
 "5" 1234 30 04012015
 "2" 1234 30 05012015
 "5" 4321 30 07012016
 "2" 9876 60 05012016
 "10" 9876 30 07012016
 ;
run;
```

See observation 3 rolled up into 2, 8 into 7, etc.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're checking for changes between consecutive days and if not, combining periods. It's very commonly done in SAS but isn't that straightforward when starting out. If you search on communities.sas.com you'll find answers to this question.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far, as posted, this does not meet SO rules

Comment: This is not, as Reeza pointed out, beginner stuff. But a few hints: `retain` variables & `by` groups. Also, `lag` could be used.

Comment: Are your supply dates that clean? People rarely fill their prescriptions on such a neat schedule? The data needs to be reflective of reality.

Comment: You know what...treat this as the medicine cabinet problem. Especially if your next question will be what drugs are taken together. Basically create a record for every day and then roll it back up to the levels you need after. You need to have space for that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution relying on *retain* variables. It is only one among many, and it uses rather advanced techniques that could scare the crap out of a beginner. You have been warned ;)

The use of `goto` & labels (ending with `:`) is not very common and in *most* cases can be avoided. But in a situation like this, it seems warranted, mainly for concision.

```
data have;
  informat id 4. dose 3. supply 3. date mmddyy8.;
  format date mmddyy10.;
  input id dose supply date;
  datalines;
1234  5 30 01012015
1234 10 30 02012015
1234 10 30 03012015
1234  5 30 04012015
1234  2 30 05012015
4321  5 30 07012016
9876  2 30 05012016
9876  2 30 06012016
9876 10 30 07012016
;
```

We first make sure our data is properly sorted.

```
proc sort data=have;
  by id date;
run;
```

#### The Solution

The `retain` statement will make it so that values for the declared variables are kept in memory as the data step iterates over rows of the `have` data set.

Note that the `_i` suffix is added to the existing variables from `have`, *i* standing for *input*.

```
data want(drop=id_i dose_i supply_i date_i);
  format id dose supply 8. date mmddyy10.;
  retain id dose supply date;
  set have(rename=(id=id_i dose=dose_i supply=supply_i date=date_i)) end=last;

  if _N_ = 1 then goto propagate;

  if id_i = id and dose_i = dose then do;
    supply = supply + supply_i;
    goto checklast;
  end;

  * When id or dose is different from previous row, ;
  * we write the observation to the want table.     ;
  output;

  propagate:
  id     = id_i;
  dose   = dose_i;
  supply = supply_i;
  date   = date_i;

  checklast:
  if last then output;
run;
```

**A few things to note here:**

- `_N_` is an automatic SAS variable indicating the current iteration number
- `end=last` (used as a parameter to the `set` statement) creates a variable called `last` (this is an arbitrary name) that will take on value `1` when the last observation is read from `have`, and `0` otherwise. We use it as a boolean variable at the end of the data step.
- Keep in mind, in trying to figure this out, that a data step functions just like a `for` loop, iterating over rows of its source table.

#### Results

```
id    dose   supply    date
1234    5       30    01/01/2015
1234    10      60    02/01/2015
1234    5       30    04/01/2015
1234    2       30    05/01/2015
4321    5       30    07/01/2016
9876    2       60    05/01/2016
9876    10      30    07/01/2016
```

Comment: Oh wow, yes, this definitely is not a beginner-level problem. I feel like I've bitten off more than I can chew with this. I've just ran this and it worked perfectly for what I was expecting. I'm going to step through this and see if that doesn't help me better understand it all. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach uses the NOTSORTED option which doesn't require any predetermine knowledge about the data set.

```
data have;
informat date mmddyy8.;
format date date9.;
 input dose  id $ supply date ;
 datalines;
5 1234 30 01012015
10 1234 30 02012015
10 1234 30 03012015
5 1234 30 04012015
2 1234 30 05012015
5 4321 30 07012016
2 9876 30 05012016
2 9876 30 06012016
10 9876 30 07012016
 ;
run;

proc sort data=have;
  by id date;
run;

data want;
set have;
by id dose notsorted;
retain n_days;

if first.dose or first.id then n_days=0;

n_days+supply;

if last.dose then output;

run;
```