# How to parse format from given data?

Tags: sas

I want to extend the question asked  at [Sum consecutive observations by some variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361194/sum-consecutive-observations-by-some-variable).

When I define the following macro variable

```
%let varnames=id dose supply date;
```

Since I don't know the fomat of the original data, how do I get the format for the rename automatically to apply it in the following extract of the above link?

```
data want(drop=id_i dose_i supply_i date_i);
  format id dose supply 8. date mmddyy10.;
  retain id dose supply date;
  set have(rename=(id=id_i dose=dose_i supply=supply_i date=date_i)) end=last;
```

Comment: Why are you renaming and why is there an i? We don't know what you have or what you're trying to achieve and It's not clear how this relates to the previous question you've linked to either.

Comment: You don't need a format in order to use the rename. Please add an example of what you want to do so we can help.

Comment: The solution in the question you've linked to is inefficient, I've posted a new solution in that post. You have no data so I have no idea if it will work for your or not.